# install4j assets in Mac retina display

Tags: macos, retina-display, install4j

I created an installer for Mac OS X and I noticed all the images being used (in banners and such) are blurry on retina display Macs.

AFAIK when building a retina display app, you provide two images (one normal def, and one high def) and OS X uses the right one.

I tried using the high resolution image but it pushed all of my content to the side.

Are retina displays supported by install4j? I know they are supported for launcher icons, but how do I configure high resolution assets for my installer pages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 5.1.x, there is no support for high-definition images. In install4j 6 it will be possible to place a file with an additional `@2x` after the name (e.g. `image.png` and `image@2x.png`) into the same directory as the selected image and install4j will pick it up and use it on retina displays.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Is there a public issue/ticket that I can follow to be notified when this functionality is available? What's the Install4j 6 target release date?

Comment: Q4/2014, you can subscribe to RSS at http://www.ej-technologies.com/download/install4j/changelog.html